# IBM Domino Administrator - issue with High DPI display

Tags: windows-10, lotus-notes, high-dpi, high-resolution

To be short: currently the question is how to disable DPI-awareness in IBM Notes/Admin/Designer? As otherwise the [IBM Domino Admin looks ugly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T54bf.jpg).

This solution doesn't help: [Superb fix for high DPI problems with Notes and Windows](http://mattwhite.me/blog/2016/1/8/superb-fix-for-high-dpi-problems-with-notes-and-windows)

IBM Notes/Admin/Designer 9.0.1 FP6 on Win 10 Pro with 2560 x 1440 "14 display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greg Sikοrski from Polymorph had a fix that worked for his Surface, and it too worked for me on my Windows 10 instance.

http://www.polymorph.co.uk/content/blog-posts/fix-for-lotus-notes-display-issues-on-surface-pro-high-dpi/

In a nutshell, you will need to edit a manifest file, assuming a default installation location of Notes 9.0.1 FP4 (or higher), found at **C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\framework\rcp\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.rcp.base_9.0.1.20131002-1404\win32\x86\notes2.exe.manifest**

First, add **xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"** as a new property to the <assembly> node so that

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
```

becomes

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
```

Then add the following block as the last element in the <assembly> tag:

```
    <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
            <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
```

So the final file will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="X86"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
            />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
            <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

Finally, close Notes/Designer/Admin completely then restart the application(s).

Comment: No problem! It took me a while to find as well. I suspect the same fix can be applied on other application EXE manifest files though other apps seem to be behaving a bit more sanely than my notes apps.